# Dealing with Foreign Characters in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I am working with a large number of foreign characters in SQL and I cannot seem to get them to save correctly;

```
JÃºlio CÃ©sar
LuisÃ£o
```

What is the best way to deal with special characters in mysql is it a setting in the data formats or do you format the data in php before you add it to the database?

Thanks

Comment: set character set of your page to UTF-8 and try

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the encoding of your database (and tables) to utf8, set the connection encoding to utf8, and use utf8 as the encoding of the php files themselves.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like "double encoding".  It is discussed in
http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll